# Will DataAnnotations work on interfaces?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I have in interface with a validation attribute like

```
public interface MyInterface
{
    [RegularExpression(@"^[A-Za-z0-9\-_ ]+$", ErrorMessage = "No bad characters"]
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and I want implementations of it to be able to add more validation, like

```
public class MyImplementation : IIdentifiable
{
    [MaxLength(100), Error Message = "Length must be <= 100"]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

However when I'm testing `MyImplementation` I noticed that the regex validation isn't happening. Is this expected? If so, how can I make an attribute on an interface get passed down to implementations? Or can I?

Comment: You cannot! Base class needs to implement an interface! You have to use an abstract class instead interfaces if you want to achieve this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I would not expect it to work.  If you are using the interface for your model binding, then I might expect that interface attributes to be reflected by MVC and those get used, but not the concrete class.  In this case, I suspect you are binding to the concrete class, and reflection is retrieving attributes from that class, and not caring about the interface.

Attributes are meta data applied to reflection members-- so it depends on whether MyImplementation or MyInterface is relfected which one is used.

Comment: Well, it shouldn't be this way. When you retrieve custom attributes, you can tell the method that you want inherited ones too.